# Layouts en Qt Creator (Tamaño mínimo de los pushbutton)

Tags: qt, qt-creator

He realizado el diseño de una app con qt creator colocando a los botones el tamaño que he necesitado. El problema es que al utilizar ahora los layouts (grid en concreto), los botones cambian su tamaño y ocupan más que el espacio del que dispongo en pantalla.
Intento redimensionarlos pero sin éxito. El tamaño vertical del botón no es problema pero el horizontal (es decir, el ancho), al ejecutar la aplicación cambia y hace que aumente el tamaño de la ventana y no quepa en la pantalla.
¿Se os ocurre alguna solución?.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Si únicamente te interesa limitar el tamaño máximo y mínimo, en el editor de formularios, al seleccionar el botón, encontrarás, bajo la categoría `QWidget`, las propiedades `minimumSize` y `maximumSize`. Configúralas al gusto para limitar el tamaño máximo y mínimo del widget en cuestión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para establecer un tamaño fijo independientemente del tamaño del widget contenedor, tienes dos opciones:

- Estableces el mismo tamaño en `minimumSize` y `maximumSize`
- Despliegas la propiedad `sizePolicy` y configuras `Horizontal Policy` y/o `Vertical Policy` a `Fixed`. Al hacerlo, el widget cogerá como tamaño fijo el indicado en `maximumSize`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que comentas de que los widgets no entran en pantalla posiblemente se deba a que algún contenedor o layout está configurado de forma incorrecta y eso fuerza a que los widgets ocupen más de lo necesario... revisa todas las propiedades que aparezcan en negrita de los widgets y layouts.

Comment: Selecciono todos los widgets, con el botón derecho escojo la opción lay out y escojo grid. Tras esto, redimensiono y todo bien. El problema es que al ejecutar, si modifico el tamaño de la ventana, estos no cambian su tamaño, ese es el problema en concreto.

Comment: @user3224353 lo que está sucediendo es que el layout que creas no está anclado al diálogo. Para crear un layout a nivel del diálogo no tienes que seleccionar todos los componentes que están dentro del diálogo sino el diálogo en sí... El layout del diálogo (así como el layout propio de cada widget) tiene como característica principal que no aparece destacado en rojo en el editor... asi que si ves el grid pintado en rojo lo estás haciendo mal

Comment: Ok, tras arreglar eso, no puedo reducir el tamaño de la ventana, alcanza un límite horizontal que no encuentro donde viene definido y quedan los pushbuttons demasiado grandes pero no quiero que tengan un tamaño fijo. Con los LCD no me pasa.

Comment: @user3224353 te falta práctica para trabajar con layouts. haz pruebas con diálogos más simples y ve escalando poco a poco. Los comentarios no son para ir solucionando todo lo que te va sucediendo sobre la marcha así como tampoco está en el imaginario de [es.so] el responder automáticamente a todo lo que se pregunte... en ese aspecto te toca pelearte un poco con el tema.

Comment: Claro que me falta práctica, por eso estoy trabajando con ello ahora mismo. El problema es que de la facultad que provengo, no enseñan prácticamente nada de interfaces gráficas y me cuesta muchísimas horas solucionar una chorrada como la que me ocurre y no tengo a nadie a quien preguntar. De todas formas, lo que tu me comentas no me ayuda en nada, no me aclara nada de lo que he preguntado ya que no se corresponde lo que pregunto con lo que respondes, igualmente te agradezco tu tiempo desinteresado. Saludos.

Comment: @user3224353 *"al ejecutar la aplicación cambia y hace que aumente el tamaño de la ventana y no quepa en la pantalla"* ahí no indicas que el botón no se redimensiona al cambiar el tamaño de la ventana sino que dices que la ventana no entra en la pantalla. si mi primera respuesta no es acertada es porque has redactado mal la pregunta. Cuando te has explicado correctamente te he dado la clave a ese problema en 5 líneas y después has empezado a comentar otro problema que te ha surgido a continuación... si quieres una respuesta completa asegúrate de que la pregunta es igualmente completa.

Comment: @user3224353 contestamos a las preguntas de forma desinteresada... pero no tenemos bola de cristal ni somos adivinos. El punto de entrada es la situación que indicas en la pregunta. Si la pregunta está mal redactada o es incorrecta dificilmente la respuesta va a poder arreglar tu problema. Por otro lado siento que en clase no te explicasen cómo va la UI... a mi tampoco me lo explicaron y empecé a hacer lo que te he dicho... ejemplos sencillos y añadiendo dificultad de forma gradual.

Comment: @user3224353 No hay un máster de UIs y tampoco puedes encadenar preguntas en los comentarios porque se desvirtua la pregunta principal